# My Python Regex code isn't finding consecutive sets of characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to code a program to find if there are three consecutive sets of double letters in a .txt file (E.G. bookkeeper). So far I have:

```
import re

text = open(r'C:\Users\Jimbo.Wimbo\Desktop\List.txt')

for line in text:
   
   x = re.finditer(r'((\w)\2)+', line)
   if True:
      print("Yes")
   Else:
      print("No")
```

`List.txt` has 5 words. There is one word with three consecutive sets of double letters right at the end, but it prints 5 "Yes"'s. What can I do to fix it using re and os?

Comment: `if True:` always succeeds, it's not testing anything meaningful.

Comment: `Else:` is a syntax error, it should be lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `re.finditer()`, you can just use `re.search()`.

Your regexp is wrong, it will match at least 1 set of duplicate characters, not 3.

`if True:` doesn't do anything useful. It doesn't mean "if the last assignment was a truthy value". You need to test the result of the regexp search.

Use `any()` to test if the condition matches any line in the file. Your code will print Yes or No for each line in the file.

```
if any(re.search(r'((\w)\2)){3}', line) for line in text):
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex is incorrect.
A good way to check your regex is to use an online regex checker, and you can test your regex against any number of strings you provide.

Here is one possible solution to your query:

```py
import re

text = open(r'C:\Users\Jimbo.Wimbo\Desktop\List.txt')

for line in text:
    x = len(re.findall(r'(.)\1', line))

    if x == 3:
        print(f"Found a word with 3 duplicate letters : {line}")
    else:
        print(f"Word: {line}, Duplicate letters : {x}")
```

Hope this helps.